# Differencing my training set data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, differencing

I'm trying to difference the non-stationary data in my training set with ndiff() and nsdiff(), but R returns the following:

> Warning: The chosen seasonal unit root test encountered an error when
> testing for the first difference. From +.default(): non-numeric
> argument to binary operator 0 seasonal differences will be used.
> Consider using a different unit root test.

The training set is based on quarterly interest rates, where I've created a time series that is split into a training set and a validation set. My analysis is based on the training set. I've also created a tsibble of the training set, on which I've performed tests and illustrated with graphs.

After I've successfully run ADF and KPSS tests on the training set and determined that it's non-stationary, I can't for the life of me figure out how to perform differencing on it before further decomposing and replicating the seasonal adjustment.

The training set is not a data frame, but is listed under Values as a time series with mode set as character. Will changing the mode to numeric (which I can't figure out how to do), make differencing possible?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the data. Can you share a sample of your data using dput?

Comment: Never done that before, so I'm not sure how to. Do you know if it's possible to change the mode from 'character' to a binary mode in the time series?

Answer (score 0):

After scrutinizing the code for a day, I solved the problem by changing the original data's 'value'-column from *character* to *numeric*. Now everything runs smoothly.